# Using the navigator.share() api, how do I share only the information for one object?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, I'm trying to use the `navigator.share()` API on a series of articles displaying with a tagged template literal. The problem is that when I click on the share button, all the elements of each object are shared.

I think the problem comes down to this snippet here:

```
const shareData = {
  title: "example.com",
  text: blogArticles.map((titles) => titles.title),
  url: blogArticles.map((urls) => urls.url)
};
```

**How do I share only the object's `key:value` pair for the article shared and not all of the object elements?**

```js
const blogArticles = [
  {
    date: "11/24/2021",
    title: "the querySelectorAll DOM API",
    minutesToRead: 10,
    tags: ["javascript", "html"],
    image: "https://placekitten.com/1600/900",
    altText: "image of kittens",
    teaser:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod",
    url: "articles/queryselectorall-dom-api.html"
  },
  {
    date: "11/24/2021",
    title: "the difference between named and anonymous functions",
    minutesToRead: 10,
    tags: ["javascript", "html"],
    image: "https://placekitten.com/1601/900",
    altText: "image of kittens",
    teaser:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod",
    url: "articles/difference-between-named-and-anonymous-functions.html"
  },
  {
    date: "11/24/2021",
    title: "css animations explained",
    minutesToRead: 10,
    tags: ["javascript", "html"],
    image: "https://placekitten.com/1602/900",
    altText: "image of kittens",
    teaser:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod",
    url: "articles/css-animations-explained.html"
  }
];

//pass blogArticles data
function blogArticlesTemplate(articles) {
  return `
    <div class="tease-post">
      <div class="tease-post__container">
        <h5 class="tease-post__meta">
          <span class="tease-post__meta--date">${articles.date}</span>
        </h5>
        <h2 class="tease-post__title"><a href="${articles.url}">${articles.title}</a></h2>
        <div class="tease-post__details">
          <h4><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> ${articles.minutesToRead} minute read</h4>
          <h4><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> ${articles.tags}</h4>
          <h4 class="share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share</h4>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <img class="tease-post__img" src="${articles.image}" alt="${articles.altText}">
        <div class="tease-post__text">
          <p>${articles.teaser}</p>

          <a href="//${articles.url}" class="tease-post__more">[read more]</a>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>    
  `;
}

document.getElementById('blogTeaserList').innerHTML = `
  ${blogArticles.map(blogArticlesTemplate).join('')}
  `;

//sharing
const shareData = {
  title: "example.com",
  text: blogArticles.map((titles) => titles.title),
  url: blogArticles.map((urls) => urls.url)
};

const shareButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".share");

if ("share" in navigator) {
  shareButtons.forEach((shareButton) => {
    shareButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      navigator
        .share(shareData)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Shared", shareData);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    });
  });
} else {
  shareButtons.forEach((shareButton) => {
    shareButton.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.tease-post {
  max-width: 350px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.share {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<div id="blogTeaserList"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the article data associated with each `shareButton` using the index of the share button. As your `shareButtons` are generated based on the article data, you can use the index while looping over your `shareButtons` [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) to grab the article data associated with the share button that was clicked. The index can be grabbed using the [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#parameters) of your `.forEach()` loop. Then, whenever you click, you can use the index along with the `blogArticles` to build your `data` object that you want to share:

```
shareButtons.forEach((shareButton, i) => { // `i` is the index of the associated data for the shareButton
  shareButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const shareData = {
        title: "example.com",
        text: blogArticles[i].title, // use index to get associated article data
        url: blogArticles[i].url
      };
      // ... remaining code ...
```

See full example below:

```js
const blogArticles = [
  {
    date: "11/24/2021",
    title: "the querySelectorAll DOM API",
    minutesToRead: 10,
    tags: ["javascript", "html"],
    image: "https://placekitten.com/1600/900",
    altText: "image of kittens",
    teaser:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod",
    url: "articles/queryselectorall-dom-api.html"
  },
  {
    date: "11/24/2021",
    title: "the difference between named and anonymous functions",
    minutesToRead: 10,
    tags: ["javascript", "html"],
    image: "https://placekitten.com/1601/900",
    altText: "image of kittens",
    teaser:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod",
    url: "articles/difference-between-named-and-anonymous-functions.html"
  },
  {
    date: "11/24/2021",
    title: "css animations explained",
    minutesToRead: 10,
    tags: ["javascript", "html"],
    image: "https://placekitten.com/1602/900",
    altText: "image of kittens",
    teaser:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod",
    url: "articles/css-animations-explained.html"
  }
];

//pass blogArticles data
function blogArticlesTemplate(articles) {
  return `
    <div class="tease-post">
      <div class="tease-post__container">
        <h5 class="tease-post__meta">
          <span class="tease-post__meta--date">${articles.date}</span>
        </h5>
        <h2 class="tease-post__title"><a href="${articles.url}">${articles.title}</a></h2>
        <div class="tease-post__details">
          <h4><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> ${articles.minutesToRead} minute read</h4>
          <h4><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> ${articles.tags}</h4>
          <h4 class="share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share</h4>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <img class="tease-post__img" src="${articles.image}" alt="${articles.altText}">
        <div class="tease-post__text">
          <p>${articles.teaser}</p>

          <a href="//${articles.url}" class="tease-post__more">[read more]</a>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>    
  `;
}

document.getElementById('blogTeaserList').innerHTML = `
  ${blogArticles.map(blogArticlesTemplate).join('')}
  `;


const shareButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".share");

if ("share" in navigator) {
  shareButtons.forEach((shareButton, i) => {
    shareButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const shareData = {
        title: "example.com",
        text: blogArticles[i].title,
        url: blogArticles[i].url
      };
      navigator
        .share(shareData)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Shared", shareData);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    });
  });
} else {
  shareButtons.forEach((shareButton) => {
    shareButton.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.tease-post {
  max-width: 350px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.share {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<div id="blogTeaserList"></div>
```

---

Overall, there are some slight improvements you can do to your overall code:

1. The first is to remove the template when you're setting your HTML: `` innerHTML = `${blogArticles.map(...).join('')}` ``. The `join()` method here already returns a string, so there isn't a need to wrap it in a template literal (although, I acknowledge this may have been done for formatting sake).
2. You can use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) instead of adding multiple event listeners to each `shareButton`. This means you only need to create one event listener and also no longer need to loop over each `shareButton` element. This leads to better performance over creating multiple event listeners for each button. As we're no longer using a for loop like we were above, obtaining the index needs to be done in a slightly different way. To achieve this, I've added a `data-article` [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), where the value for this data attribute then be obtained from the clicked element. The value stored on this data attribute is the index of the data from your articles array associated with the share button (created while mapping `blogArticles`).

See changes below:

```js
const blogArticles = [{ date: "11/24/2021", title: "the querySelectorAll DOM API", minutesToRead: 10, tags: ["javascript", "html"], image: "https://placekitten.com/1600/900", altText: "image of kittens", teaser: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod", url: "articles/queryselectorall-dom-api.html" }, { date: "11/24/2021", title: "the difference between named and anonymous functions", minutesToRead: 10, tags: ["javascript", "html"], image: "https://placekitten.com/1601/900", altText: "image of kittens", teaser: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod", url: "articles/difference-between-named-and-anonymous-functions.html" }, { date: "11/24/2021", title: "css animations explained", minutesToRead: 10, tags: ["javascript", "html"], image: "https://placekitten.com/1602/900", altText: "image of kittens", teaser: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus blanditiis magni natus! Blanditiis quibusdam mod", url: "articles/css-animations-explained.html" } ];

function blogArticlesTemplate(articles, i) {
  return `
    <div class="tease-post">
      <div class="tease-post__container">
        <h5 class="tease-post__meta">
          <span class="tease-post__meta--date">${articles.date}</span>
        </h5>
        <h2 class="tease-post__title"><a href="${articles.url}">${articles.title}</a></h2>
        <div class="tease-post__details">
          <h4><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> ${articles.minutesToRead} minute read</h4>
          <h4><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> ${articles.tags}</h4>
          <h4 class="share" data-article="${i}"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share</h4>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <img class="tease-post__img" src="${articles.image}" alt="${articles.altText}">
        <div class="tease-post__text">
          <p>${articles.teaser}</p>

          <a href="//${articles.url}" class="tease-post__more">[read more]</a>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>    
  `;
}

// `insertAdjacentHTML` is generally faster than using `.innerHTML`, as it doesn't need to tear down the old child-nodes of the container.
const blogTeasterListElem = document.getElementById('blogTeaserList');
blogTeasterListElem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", blogArticles.map(blogArticlesTemplate).join('')); 

if ("share" in navigator) {
  blogTeasterListElem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const clickedItem = e.target;
    if (clickedItem.matches(".share")) {
      const idx = Number(clickedItem.dataset.article);
      navigator
        .share({
          title: "example.com",
          text: blogArticles[idx].title,
          url: blogArticles[idx].url
        }).then(() => {
          console.log("Shared", shareData);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  });
} else {
  document.querySelectorAll(".share").forEach((shareButton) => {
    shareButton.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.tease-post {
  max-width: 350px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.share {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<div id="blogTeaserList"></div>
```